# Запись домена в переменную

Tags: redirect, yii

У меня есть много зеркальных доменов (site.com,site.net,site.ru,ee.site.net,...). 
Скрипты выполняются на одном сервере. Использую Yii Framework.

Как мне записать домен в переменную?

Пробовал urlManager, но ничего не получилось. Может быть htaccess?

Спасибо!

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?

Comment: На $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] пожалуй останавливаюсь.
Каждый домен принадлежит какому-то региону. По имени домена я собираюсь выяснить какая эта страна или регион или город, чтобы вернуть соответствующий контент. Выяснять мне удобнее в моделях, которые наследуют CActiveRecord. Но в CActiveRecord писать метод для определения страны как то не красиво. 
Наверно придется впихнуть в базовый класс Yii метод, который будет возвращать id страны.